# Antichain and predense set

Tags: set-theory

I am trying to prove

> $A$ is a maximal antichain iff $A$ is predense.

It is problem 16 from link [here](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/logic/teaching/2011SS/models_of_set_theory_1/problems04.pdf). If $A$ is maximal antichain then is easy to prove that $A$ is predense. I stuck on proof that predense set is maximal antichain: how to prove that elements in predense set $A$ are pairwise incompatible? Can you help me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in the general hypothesis of Problem 16, it is already assumed that $A$ is an *antichain*, so only maximality needs to be proved.

(Anyway, for example the full partial order is dense for sure, but is usually not antichain..)